# How to fire the onclick event before the checked property change?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Simple example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb" />   

document.getElementById("cb").onclick = function(){
    if(this.checked){
        console.log("Change from checked to unchecked");
    } else {
        console.log("Change from unchecked to checked");         
    }
};
```

But when I run it, it give the opposite result.
And the conclusion I came up with is that the `checked` property change before the `onclick` event is fired.
So my question is: how could I fire the `onclick` event before the `checked` property change?

Comment: Does it have to be onclick? why not just use onchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use `onchange` event instead of `onclick`.

**UPDATE:**

your **if** condition is wrong, when the control is checked, you are showing **Change from checked to unchecked**

Comment: @wong2 your **if** condition is wrong, when the control is checked, you are showing **Change from checked to unchecked**

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb" />   

document.getElementById("cb").onchange = function(){
    if(this.checked){
        console.log("Change from unchecked to checked");
    } else {
        console.log("Change from checked to unchecked");         
    }
};
```